# What is the correct way of issuing your own token?

Tags: tokens, dapp

There is an esoio.token contract.
This contract be used for issuing and storing many tokens starting with EOS.

However, is it possible to issue tokens without using the eosio.token contract?

What is the best way to issue tokens - to use the eosio.token contract, or to copy the eosio.token contract under new name and issue there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first line of `token::create` is `require_auth( _self );`. So I think only the contract account `eosio.token` can create the tokens. What you can always do is to reutilize this contract in an account that belongs to you:

`cleos set contract your.account $EOSPATH/build/contracts/eosio.token`

So you have control of all the features and can create all the tokens you need. Now I'm just curious if we have a way to have permission to create tokens using the `eosio.token` account...

Answer (score 3):

You can view the eosdactoken contract here - https://github.com/eosdac/eosdactoken

We've implemented some extra functions for membership which will tie into our forthcoming DAC voting and worker proposal contracts.